# Is there a way to access linkedin signal updates through API

Tags: api, signals, linkedin-api

Using the following URL,

http://www.linkedin.com/signal/?type=updates&keywords=linkedin&pplSearchOrigin=GLHD&pageKey=member-home&search=Search

I can get all the recent updates of the keyword entered. Is there a way to access this signal information of linkedin through API.

If so could you please let me know on how to do it.

Thanks and Regards,
Arjun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Signal API in the LinkedIn Open Developer Program at this time.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear so. Per the documentation, you can only pull network updates based on the type, and they appear to be limited to the user and their first-degree connections:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/get-network-updates-and-statistics-api